# How can highlight all the automatic-fields or only references in Microsoft Word 2010+?

Tags: microsoft-word, syntax-highlighting

Is there any way that I can highlight, to quickly check, all the internal references in a word document?

The current version that I'm working with is Office 2010 on Windows or Office 2011 on a Mac OS.

Answer (score 4):

Word has a number of options for field highlighting: File | Options | Advanced | Field Shading (under the "Show Document Content" heading).

Also in advanced find, expand (more button) and under the special button is "field".